# c++ undefined reference to default constructor

Tags: c++, linker-errors, default-constructor

I am creating a C++ 11 program which compiles but fails to link.  I have traced the error (shown at the bottom of this post) to a single line of code:

```
            m_equities[symbol] = temp;
```

where m_equities is defined as:

```
    map<string, EquityInDB> m_equities;
```

and temp is an instance of EquityInDB.

Can someone explain why this one line of code is causing the linker error below?   It looks like that one line is trying to create an instance of my EquityInDB class using the default constructor (there is none).  My EquityInDB class requires parameters in the constructor.

(Note: Commenting out the one assignment line above lets everything compile)

> g++  -o MetaStockDB main.o date.o tradingday.o equity.o metastockdb.o
>   msfileio.o equityindb.o bytearray.o     metastockdb.o: In function
>   `std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> > const,
>   EquityInDB>::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&,
>   0ul>(std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&,
>   std::tuple<>&, std::_Index_tuple<0ul>, std::_Index_tuple<>)':
>   Makefile:254: recipe for target 'MetaStockDB' failed
>   /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/tuple:1586: undefined reference to`
>   EquityInDB::EquityInDB()'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `m_equities[symbol]` creates an elment using the default constructor, if there is no elment in the map for that key. So using `operator[]` requires the default constructor to exists.

You should use `insert` and `std::make_pair` instead.

[std::map operator_at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> 1: Inserts `value_type(key, T())` if the key does not exist. [...] `mapped_type` must meet the requirements of `CopyConstructible` and `DefaultConstructible`. If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

and

> [...]**Return value:** Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with key key existed.`

Comment: Wow - I killed 2 hours on this.  I wish that were documented somewhere (or perhaps just easier to find)

Comment: @TSG [std::map operator_at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at): `[...]Return value: Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with key key existed.` and `1: Inserts value_type(key, T()) if the key does not exist. [...] mapped_type must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible and DefaultConstructible.`

Comment: I wonder, @t.niese , is there any way to subvert this behaviour? Beyond making a wrapper class for std::map that overrides the operator[], which I feel would suck, I can't think of anything else...

Comment: @AegisHexad If the object is not default constructable then the only way is to use `std::make_pair()` in combination with `insert`. I'm pretty sure that overwriting the `operator[]` in a way that it will not create a new element if the key does not exists, will be problematic (or only possible if `second` is a pointer), because what value should the returned pair have for `second` if `second` cannot be set to `nullptr`?